# How to see if a File object is a directory in /data/user/0/[package_name]/files/ in Android

Tags: android, file, android-permissions

I have a non-empty folder "/foo" under /data/user/0/[package_name]/files which i used to download a file from a service. When i am doing:

```
File sourceFolder = new File("/data/user/0/[package_name]/files/foo");
if(sourceFolder.isDirectory())
    FileUtility.deleteFile(sourceFolder);
```

It is unable to recognize that the sourceFolder is an existing directory. Hence not going inside the if statement. My Manifest permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and yes i am explicitly asking the read write permission of external storage using:

```
this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

I am not sure why it is unable to identify that the path provided is an existing directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a non-empty folder "/foo" under /data/user/0/[package_name]/files

So this:

```
File sourceFolder = new File("/data/user/0/[package_name]/foo");
```

should be this:

```
File sourceFolder = new File("/data/user/0/[package_name]/files/foo");
```

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo. It does reference to ../files/foo